# Submit to 2 different PHP forms using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am facing issues when I want to send 2 forms with different values using 2 different PHP pages.

My ajax code like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var form = $('#main_form_new');
          var submit = $('.sbbtn');
          var alert = $('.form_result');
          form.on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
              url: 'ajax/category.php',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'html',
              data: form.serialize(),
              beforeSend: function() {
                alert.fadeOut();
                submit.html('Saving Changes....');
              },
              success: function(data) {
                alert.html(data).fadeIn();
                form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                submit.html('Save Changes');
              },
              error: function(e) {
                console.log(e)
              }
            });
          });
          });
```

For the second form I changed the var and replaced it as

```
          var itemform = $('#item_main_itemform_new');
          var itemsubmit = $('.itemsbbtn');
          var itemalert = $('.item_itemform_result');
          itemform.on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
              url: 'ajax/items.php',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'html',
              data: itemform.serialize(),
              beforeSend: function() {
                itemalert.fadeOut();
                itemsubmit.html('Saving Changes....');
              },
              success: function(data) {
                itemalert.html(data).fadeIn();
                itemform.trigger('reset'); // reset itemform
                itemsubmit.html('Save Changes');
              },
              error: function(e) {
                console.log(e)
              }
            });
          });
```

This does not work as I really do not know the reason. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: form does not get processed

Comment: do you have both forms on the same page? or the second one is comming out of first ajax?

Comment: Its on the same page.

Comment: I got the culprit. When I replaced the var, I have somehow, changed the form id, `var itemform = $('#item_main_itemform_new');` it was suppose to be `var itemform = $('#item_main_form_new');` Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't repeat yourself.**

If you need the same functionality twice, don't copy and paste your code. Make a function, use variables for the variable parts, call that function twice.

```
$(function() {
    function formSubmitHandler(options) {
        return function (e) {
            var $form = $(this),
                $submit = $(options.submit),
                $alert = $(options.alert);

            e.preventDefault();

            $alert.fadeOut();
            $submit.html('Saving Changes...').prop({disabled: true});

            $.post(options.url, $form.serialize())
            .done(function (data) {
                $alert.html(data).fadeIn();
                $form.trigger('reset');
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $alert.html(textStatus).fadeIn();
                console.log(arguments);
            })
            .always(function () {
                $submit.html('Save Changes').prop({disabled: false});
            });
        };
    }

    $('#main_form_new').submit(formSubmitHandler({
        url: 'ajax/category.php',
        submit: '.sbbtn',
        alert: '.form_result'
    }));

    $('#item_main_itemform_new').submit(formSubmitHandler({
        url: 'ajax/items.php',
        submit: '.itemsbbtn',
        alert: '.item_itemform_result'
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this and update you in sometime

Comment: Awesome! Perfect!. Thanks so much. This could have not been easier. Sorry for the late reply though as I was not available to test. Upvoted and Accepted. +100